# Locus of a point from which tangents drawn to a fixed circle are inclined at a constant angle $\theta$ and area bounded by it

Tags: contest-math, analytic-geometry, circles, area, coordinate-systems

[image]

The question is given above. I'm able to get the locus, however, I'm unable to comment on the area bounded by it.

We can get the locus using the relation $\tan\theta=\frac{2LR}{L^{2}-R^{2}}$ where $R$ is radius of circle and $L$ is length of tangent from the given point. We can write $L=\sqrt{h^{2}+k^{2}-25}$. On solving we get the locus as 
$$\tan^{2}\theta(x^{2}+y^{2}-50)^{2}=100(x^{2}+y^{2}-25)$$
How do we comment on the area bounded by this curve for $\theta\in (\frac{\pi}{2},\pi)$ and $\theta\in(\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2})$. Alternately, is there another way to see the area bounded by the locus of such a point without finding the locus.

Comment: You can try substitution $x^2+y^2=u$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of the locus you have found looks exact, but it's hard for me to find out its origin (I don't understand your $\tan\theta=\frac{2LR}{L^{2}-R^{2}}$ and how I can exploit it).

But there is a simpler approach.

If $M$ is any point in the plane, let $T$ be one of the two points of tangency of a tangent issued from $M$ to the circle with center $O$ and radius $5$. In right triangle $MTO$, we have

$$MO=\frac{5}{\sin(\theta/2)}$$

Therefore, for a constant $\theta$, i.e., for a constant $\sin(\theta/2)$, we have a constant distance $MO$ : the locus of such points $M$ is the circle with center $0$ and radius

$$r=\frac{5}{\sin(\theta/2)}$$

with area

$$A(\theta)=\pi \frac{25}{\sin^2(\theta/2)}$$

As $A(...)$ is a decreasing function of $\theta$ on $[(\pi/4),\pi]$, you just have to compute the value of $A$ at the *lower bound* on each interval, for example, in the third case, $[(\pi/4),(\pi/2)]$, just compute $A(\pi/4)$.

Can you take it from here ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you make a helpful sketch to find what is the area referred to in your question, between the circle and tangents,two polar angles and the curve?

I am able to recognize the two tangents and triangles with sides adjoining right angle at tangent point as $ R=5,L,h,k $ and hypotenuse
$$ \sqrt{25 +L^2} = \sqrt{h^2+k^2}. $$

And since $ \tan \frac\theta2= \frac 5L=\frac RL=t, $ you calculated

$$ \tan \theta= \frac{2t}{1-t^2} = \frac{2RL}{L^2-R^2}$$